# Augment SilverStripe UploadField

Tags: silverstripe, jquery-file-upload

I'd like the augment the HTML that gets appended to the Upload field on a file upload and add but I can't seem to find where the where the div.ss-uploadfield-item-info is added.

Specifically I'd like to add a second hidden input after the file ID field.

Answer (score 1):

You need to overwrite the template for the uploadfield, the original is in */framework/templates/UploadField.ss*. Using ->[setTemplate('YourTemplate')](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-FormField.html#_setTemplate) you can even set the template for one single instance of the UploadField.

The hidden field can either be set statically in your own template or using [HiddenField](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-HiddenField.html).

Comment: Okay I got the field in but I can't save the data. Not sure where that data is written in the save page pipeline.

I tried to overload setValue() but it seems to fire 4 times,  during the page save, but I can't pass that data extra data anywhere.

Comment: it should be saved to a File has_one or has_many relation automatically. Can you share some php code including the relevant $db and $has_ statements of your DataObject?

Comment: Well the model is [silverstripe-gallery](https://github.com/frankmullenger/silverstripe-gallery/blob/1.2-dev/code/Gallery.php) It's a many_many. I thought I'd get a jump on SS3.2 and start upgrading it. I'd liek to be able to save sort order on intial page save